# Not able to build react native project getting server returned response error 500 in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Why I am getting above error while doing `react-native run-android`. I am not able to do `react-native run-android`.

I tried cleaning Gradle but not working:

I tried this -> `cd android` and then `Gradlew clean` 
Note: I am using windows 10.
Screenshot:

[image]

package.json:
[image]
.babelrc:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need clear `node_modules`, install again, and `restart dev server` with `--reset-cache`.
Command:

install `metro-react-native-babel-preset`

`npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev`

`rmdir node_modules` (Windows)

```
npm install
npm start --reset-cache
```

and open other terminal/command window to run

`react-native run-android`

Edit: add final solution

First: in `.babelrc` replace `{ "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"] }` to `{ "presets": ["react-native"] }`. And remove node_modules and run again by commands in my answer.

Comment: Even after following your steps it is giving same error

Comment: Could you post your `.babelrc` file also ? because error from `metro-react-native-babel-preset`. I solved similar issue with babel-preset with my own project before.
Edit: I added more command to install `metro-react-native-babel-preset`. Please try.

Comment: I have added babelrc file and package.json please check it out https://imgur.com/a/j9Q12Lo

Comment: I tried `npm i metro-react-native-babel-preset --save-dev` and then react-native start and then react-native run-android doesn't work still same error. Should I edit .babelrc to react-native instead of `module:metro-react-native-babel-preset`

Comment: I think we can try 2 thing.
First: in `.babelrc` replace `{
"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}`
to
`{
"presets": ["react-native"]
}`. And remove `node_modules` and run again by commands in my answer.
IF still cannot success, remove .babelrc file and run again.

Comment: Any luck ? @fun

Comment: Works like a charm just add one point in your answer i.e `"presets": ["react-native"] ` instead of `"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]` I think this was windows specific error. In windows it is `"presets": ["react-native"] ` and for ios `"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]`

Comment: Done buddy :) Thanks once again

Comment: Can you help here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52645644/uncaught-reference-error-in-react-native

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to close terminal and re-run the "react-native run-android"? to do more steps: first close cmd terminal, then "npm i" or "yarn" , then kill the app from emulator/phone, finally: "react-native run-android".

Comment: let me try it once. I am using windows 10

Comment: OK, let me know.. :)

Comment: how to kill the app ?

Comment: I tried steps mentioned by @Tung but still getting same error

Comment: in android you easily can push "□" and then kill the app.

Comment: Oh ok got it let me check it

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the bundler could not find `babel` preset `metro-react-native-babel-preset`. So you could either install it manually by

`yarn add metro-react-native-babel-preset --dev`

If this does not work, then delete the `node_modules` directory and run `yarn` to re-install all the packages.

Comment: @abhinash I tried `yarn add metro-react-native-babel-preset --dev` it still gives same error. Now I deleted node modules and then yarn install still gives error not working :(