# Uncaught reference error in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting uncaught reference error in react native why so ? I am able to build successfully but the bundler is showing this error. How can I fix it ?

Note: I am using windows 10

Screenshot:

[image]

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "rchampz",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.0",
    "react-native-dash": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^3.5.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^6.0.0",
    "react-native-paper": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "^3.10.0",
    "react-native-timeline-theme": "^0.0.9",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.14.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["module:react-native"]
}
```

Comment: Hi again @fun do error occurs when you try remote debug ?

Comment: @TungDuong Upgarding android API version to 26 (Oreo) of virtual device helped me solve this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either include preset of react-native in .bablerc or export presets from babel.config.js like below

`module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime'
    ],
  }`

Comment: Upgarding android API version to 26 (Oreo) of virtual device helped me solve this issue

Comment: You can upgrade your android version(26+) in oreo for windows 10.This will help you out too.

Comment: Add it in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, use `react-native-cli` to create a new ReactNative project, and see the build files. I just did that, and here's what I have :

package.json

```
{
  "name": "someproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

.babelrc :

```
{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

Note that if you changed your package.json, some cleaning might be needed first

Comment: So should I install `"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.47.1"` ? Before installing new package how should I clean

Comment: clean might not be needed, I just find ReactNative (and more generally, npm) builds to be messy, especially if you try to downgrade some dependencies. `rm -rf node_modules` to remove installed modules, `watchman watch-del-all` to clean your bundler cache, then `npm install` to re-install dependencies

Comment: `"presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]` is for ios I am on windows and it should be `"presets": ["module:react-native"]`

Comment: I followed your steps but see the screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/syy2fTR

Comment: It is not RN issue I guess it is android version issue. I have created new project but after successful bundling and build I am not able to click on emulator the emulator is not working

Comment: AFAIK the bundler presets are not specific to iOS nor android